# how to change cell refence within Formula based on cell value?

Tags: google-sheets

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5F7b.png)

I have multiple formulas that sums data from a table, and where the formula says =SUM(A2:A6) I want to be able to replace the numbers 2 & 6 with values from other cells that change daily instead of replacing them every day.

So today it's =SUM(A2:A6) and =SUM(B2:B6) and 80 other formulas
but tomorrow it should be =SUM(A3:A7) and =SUM(B3:B7) and so on

How to force google sheets to use the number in the cell instead of the static numbers 2 & 6 here =SUM(A**2**:A**6**) ?

I played around with indirect function but couldn't make it work, and also found a way with to make the values 2 & 6 to increase daily based on the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,C1):INDEX(A:A, D1))
```

[image]

Comment: perfectly worked! thank you